# Adding buttons with images is distorting stackview

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have 2 textfields in a stackview that have a picker as an input (doubt this makes a difference). This is the first image attached [image]

Now when I add another horizontal stackview and add an array of buttons, it completely distorts the textfields. [image]

How do I fix this? The row of buttons need to be the same height as the text fields in the first image.

And my button labels aren't showing either.

Here is the code for the horizontal stackview:

```
hStack?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hStack?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        hStack?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        hStack?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        hStack?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        hStack = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
        hStack?.axis = .horizontal
        hStack?.distribution = .fillEqually
        hStack?.spacing = 4
        allViews.append(hStack!)
```

And here is how I am creating the buttons:

```
let arrayOfDays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
        for index in 0...6 {
            let button  = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_unchecked"), for: .normal)
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_checked"), for: .selected)
            button.setTitle(arrayOfDays[index], for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dayTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            hStack?.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }
```

The buttons need to be perfect circle, same height as the text fields in the first image and the labels should show.

Comment: At what time do you add the button stack?

Comment: on view did load.